net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException CHANGETHESIZEANDLOCATIONOFYOURAPPS
I am using ucanaccess-4.0.1 and java to create a database.
This database has over 20 tables and some tables have over 1000 rows.
I am now getting this exception below. I have never seen it before or can find anythign online about. Any help would be appreciated.
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected token: CHANGETHESIZEANDLOCATIONOFYOURAPPS required: )
Found the issue. My java logic created a faulty insert statement for 1 row. now the exception is gone. But the error message doesnt make sense.
INSERT INTO dbo_videos VALUES ('603', '33', 'Office365_OutlookWebAccessCourse, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')

looks like 'Office365_OutlookWebAccessCourse is not quoted properly

@pebbleunit yes I put that in my edit... But what does the error message mean?

Your Java logic is creating SQL statements? Don't do that. That's how you get SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use prepared statements, ORMs, basically anything else.
